# xslt current-dateTime() doesn't work in file name

Tags: datetime, xslt

I'm trying to generate some log files with a timestamp in the end of file. The code to generate file name is :

```
<xsl:variable name="timestamp" as="xs:string" select="f:transformDateTimeForFilename(current-dateTime())" />

<xsl:result-document href="logs_{$type}_{$timestamp}.xml"/>
```

The function `f:transformDateTimeForFilename` is used to remove the `:.+` in gerenated datetime.

The generated log file name is supposed to be `logs_txt_2016-12-19T110104825.xml`, but what I got is `logs_txt_.xml`. The most strange thing is the code worked fine in local unit test, but once I ran the program on a Windows server, the timestamp is gone without error logs generated.

Thanks for any proposal.

---

Update with more details :

The log file is generated inside of a template :

```
<xsl:template name="makeLogs">
    <xsl:param name="logNodes"      as="element(l:Log)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="type"          as="xs:string"      />

    <xsl:variable name="timestamp" as="xs:string" select="f:transformDateTimeForFilename(current-dateTime())"/>

    <xsl:result-document href="logs_{$type}_{$timestamp}.xml" >
      ....
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="f:transformDateTimeForFilename" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="dateTime" as="xs:dateTime"/>

    <xsl:variable name="dateTimeStringWithoutTimeZone" as="xs:string" select="substring-before(string($dateTime), '+')"/>

    <xsl:sequence select="replace($dateTimeStringWithoutTimeZone, '[:.]', '')"/>

</xsl:function>
```

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples of  XML input and XSLT code together with a precise description of the used XSLT processor to allow us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: So which XSLT processor is that, is it the same in the unit test and on the Windows server? Have you debugged `<xsl:message select="$timestamp"/>`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen good point ! On local machine it is 2.0 and not sure for the version on the server. So to make sure the code works I changed it to ```<xsl:variable name="timestamp" as="xs:string" select="f:transformDateTimeForFilename(timestamp:getcurrentISO8601Timestamp())"/>``` with ```public static String getCurrentISO8601Timestamp(){
        return ZonedDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
    }``` and a declaration of namesapce of ```timestamp```

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am confirmed that the xslt processor version is also 2.0. Any idea why that could happen ?

Comment: I would suggest to run a simple test case `replace(string(current-dateTime()), '[:.]', '')` through that XSLT processor, perhaps it has a bug with wrongly assuming that `.` inside the square brackets matches any character and therefore you end up with the empty string returned from that function. But that is just a guess to find one explanation why you get that result, you will have to debug to see what happens, I don't think we can explain that from the data you have provided, given that you get the right result on one machine and a wrong result on a different one.